# Can I have a distinct selection in a where clause on MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a selection in MySQL that returns a list of IDs. The code goes as following:

```
select 
    distinct(cit.cited_article_id) 
from gp_citation as cit,
    (SELECT id, collection_id, year,
        collection_name,
        collection_volume, collection_number, title,
        is_international_relations, is_book_review, gp_status
        FROM gp_publication
        WHERE (collection_id = 1304 OR collection_id = 577
        OR collection_ID = 387 OR collection_ID = 19
        OR collection_ID = 5739 OR collection_ID = 6245
        OR collection_ID = 6246 OR collection_ID = 6522
        OR collection_ID = 6524 OR collection_ID = 6526
        OR collection_ID = 6527 OR collection_ID = 6528
        OR collection_ID = 6529 OR collection_ID = 6530
        OR collection_ID = 6531 OR collection_ID = 150
        OR collection_ID = 6525)
        AND (year >= 2011 AND year <= 2015)
        AND is_international_relations = 1
        AND is_book_review = 0
    ) as pub
where
    pub.id = cit.citing_article_id;
```

Now I don't want to get the cited_article_id as a result but the gp_publication select, however I can not manage to turn the select around that I have a distinct list of IDs selecting entries from gp_publication.

The result should contain id, collection_id, collection_numer ect from gp_publications.

I probably could use the full statement returning the IDs as a where clause like

```
... where pub.id = < returned list of ids from above statement >
```

but is there a better way to do that without selecting from the same tables twice? gp_citation has duplicates so I need to use distinct().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like we could use use an inline view on `gp_citation`. The inline view query can contain the `DISTINCT` keyword in the SELECT list, or can use a `GROUP BY` function and aggregates.

It's not clear from the information provided which "duplicates" are to be eliminated.

Leaving the inline view `pub` as is, we can do a join to an inline view:

```
 SELECT pub.*
      , cit.*
   FROM ( SELECT p.id
               , p.collection_id
               , p.year
               , p.collection_name
               , p.collection_volume
               , p.collection_number
               , p.title
               , p.is_international_relations
               , p.is_book_review
               , p.gp_status
            FROM gp_publication p
           WHERE p.collection_id IN (1304,577,387,19,5739,6245,6246,6522,6524,6526,6527,6528,6529,6530,6531,150,6525)
             AND p.year                      >= 2011 
             AND p.year                      <= 2015
             AND p.is_international_relations = 1
             AND p.is_book_review             = 0
        ) pub
   JOIN ( SELECT c.cited_article_id
               , c.citing_article_id
            FROM gp_citation c
           GROUP
              BY c.cited_article_id
               , c.citing_article_id
        ) cit
     ON cit.citing_article_id = pub.id
  ORDER
     BY ...
```

My expectation is that an article could be "cited" by several other articles ... that is, there could be multiple rows in `gp_citation` with the same `cited_article_id` and a variety of `citing_article_id`.

If the goal is to avoid returning "duplicate" rows for `gp_publication`, assuming `id` is a unique identifier, we could do somthing like this:

```
 SELECT pub.id
      , pub.collection_id
      , pub.year
      , pub.collection_name
      , pub.collection_volume
      , pub.collection_number
      , pub.title
      , pub.is_international_relations
      , pub.is_book_review
      , pub.gp_status
   FROM ( SELECT p.id AS pub_id
            FROM ( SELECT c.cited_article_id
                        , c.citing_article_id
                     FROM gp_citation cit
                    GROUP
                       BY c.cited_article_id
                        , c.citing_article_id
                 ) cit
            JOIN gp_publication p
              ON p.id = cit.citing_article_id
           WHERE p.collection_id IN (1304,577,387,19,5739,6245,6246,6522,6524,6526,6527,6528,6529,6530,6531,150,6525)
             AND p.year                      >= 2011 
             AND p.year                      <= 2015
             AND p.is_international_relations = 1
             AND p.is_book_review             = 0
           GROUP
              BY p.id
        ) cc
   JOIN gp_publication pub
     ON pub.id = cc.pub_id
  ORDER
     BY ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but something is not right. Your first statement returns 15649 rows and the second one returns 308 rows while my statement returns 14302 distinct ids. While @fancyPants answer returns 15784 rows. I don't understand why each statement here is returning a different amount of rows?

Comment: we expect different rows counts from the two queries in this answer, because each query satisfies a different specification. The second query returns distinct rows (no duplicates) from `gp_publication`. The first query allows duplicate rows from `gp_publication` to be returned. As to something not right with the queries, the specification that each query satisfies must not be a match for the requirements provided in the question. Narrow down the specification... what resultset should be returned under what conditions. Then we can write a query that satisfies the requirements.